# Is the "_s" on this `sprintf(__('Page %s', '_s'), max($paged, $page))` just refer to a text domain?

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, themes, templates

Is the `'_s'` value in such code which can be found on [Customizing with the filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title#Customizing_with_the_filter), just refer to a string of a [text domain](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/#text-domains) as what's documented or a literal value?

```
/**
 * Filters wp_title to print a neat <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
 *
 * @param string $title Default title text for current view.
 * @param string $sep Optional separator.
 * @return string The filtered title.
 */
function theme_name_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
    if ( is_feed() ) {
        return $title;
    }

    global $page, $paged;

    // Add the blog name
    $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' );

    // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) {
        $title .= " $sep $site_description";
    }

    // Add a page number if necessary:
    if ( ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 ) && ! is_404() ) {
        $title .= " $sep " . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', '_s' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'theme_name_wp_title', 10, 2 );
```

Just for verification, but if ever it's a literal value for that arg, can you please explain what's happening to that arg in that function? Is that converted in what text domain, or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is. It might get a bit clearer if you re-format this line

```
$title .= " $sep " . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', '_s' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
```

to:

```
$title .= " $sep ";
$title .= sprintf( 
    __( 'Page %s', '_s' ), 
    max( $paged, $page ) 
);
```

The first parameter of [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.sprintf.php) expects a format which is here the return value of the `__` function. The second parameter of this function [is meant to be the text domain](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/).

**Update**:
In fact, I think its the default text domain from the starter theme [»Undersorce S«](https://github.com/Automattic/_s) from where the example code in the codex might come from.

**Update 2**:
There you go: it looks like the sample from the codex was taken from the function [`_s_wp_title`](https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/4b36cf3053b0cf9a7c19a960c396f1e923cfce36/inc/extras.php#L34). The `_s` in the function name was replaced by `theme_name` but the text domain obviously was missed out.